# Convert bmp into a correct RGB array in Python3

Tags: python

I can not write the array correctly. I don't know why python has such a issue.

```
import sys,os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from bitmap import BitMap
src=os.getcwd()
#get the current working diretory
print(src)
path=src+"\\Se.bmp"
img=Image.open(path,"r")
width, height=img.size

print(f"width={width}")
print(f"height={height}")
#turn it into RGB vlaue array
array=np.array(list(img.getdata()))

name="\\rgb array test_1a.txt"
with open(src+name,"w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for i in range(len(array)):
        file.write("\n")
        for j in range(3):
            file.writelines(str(array[i][j])+",")
```

I compare it to the value I get from https://hexed.it/ after I convert both of them to a decimal value. They are totally different. What's the issue here?

Here is the first row I got from the website https://hexed.it/. I have export it as a decimal value.

> ```
> arr = bytes([
>   # Offset 0x00000000 to 0x00000015
>   66, 77, 54, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0
> ])
> ```

This below is 1st row my output txt file.

> `254,254,254,`

Comment: BMP files have a header and store the color (if true color mode is used and not a palette) in BGR order. If this doesn't explain the difference you should show a sample of both files as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have provide some samples now.